# Relative layout inside a scrollview is not working perfectly.

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am using a relativelayout inside a scrollview,and I am adding views to that relativelayout dynamically.Eventhough the views are more than the screensize its not scrolling.
Please help in solving this task.

My ScrollView xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:fillViewport="true"


        >

     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />


</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code used for dynamically adding images:

```
     if (isOddViewNo)
                {
                    isOddViewNo=false;

                    final View view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, null);

                    iv=  (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_small);
                ImageView   iv1=  (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_big);
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);





                    iv.setX(x-45);
                    iv.setY(ypos+17);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    rl.addView(view);
                    x+=100;
                }
               else
                {
                    isOddViewNo=true;

                    final View view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, null);


                    iv=  (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_big);


                    ImageView   iv1=  (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_small);
                    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//                  iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200,200));

                    iv.setX(x-45);
                    iv.setY(ypos);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    rl.addView(view);

                    x+=178;
                }
```

My inflated sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_small"

    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_big"
    android:visibility="gone"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My screenshot:[image: As I showed my screenshot,it has many images below but couldnt able to scroll.]

Comment: Have you tryied to set the height layout param of the view added by code to wrap content instead of fill parent?

Comment: yes tried but didnt worked

Comment: First of all change to wrap content, both width and height, of the parent relativelayout in sample.xml. You are setting the x and y values to the image view inside sample.xml. try to set x and y to the whole layout (variable view).

Comment: do you want me to set imageview height to fillparent

Comment: I tried that way then my images are adding at the bottom but couldnt able to scroll

Comment: No, the height of the imageview leave hardcoded. On the code, instead of iv.setX... put view.setX... and the same for setY. And on the sample.xml change to wrapcontent the height and width of the relativelayout

Comment: Of the linearlayout, sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42727/discussion-between-user1891910-and-diego-suarez)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ScrollView height to wrap_content. Also never use fill_parent (deprecated) , use match_parent instead.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt worked,but I  have observed one thing is when I try to fix the height in   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT(1500)); it is scrolling

Comment: Have you tried setting wrap_content both on the scrollView aswell as the relativeLayout and the inflated childs? that should work.